# store check box value in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on the *Administrator page* for my website.

*Administrator* has the privilege to select six(**6**) products and change the status from *available* to *unavailable* and vice versa, using *check box*.

Available products will be shown on the front-end for the user to see along with the picture of the product.

I have a table named `used` and has a column of `value` (**VarChar**).

Connection of both *user* and *admin* page to the database works fine. My problem is I'm not sure how to store the value of the selected *check boxes*, that would change the front end's output (picture of a product on the front-end will show up if product is available).

Here are my codes:

**Admin** (not sure at all how to do this)

```
Product 1
<input type="checkbox" name="product1" value="1">Available</span></input>

Product 2
<input type="checkbox" name="product2" value="1">Available</span></input>
```

**User**

```
<?php

require_once "../db_connect.php";

$res = mysqli_query("SELECT value FROM settings WHERE name='product1'",$mysql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

$product1 = $row['value'];

$res = mysqli_query("SELECT value FROM settings WHERE name='product2'",$mysql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

$product2 = $row['value'];


if ($product1 > 0)
    {
    echo '<img src="http://mysite/image1.png" border=0>';
    }
else 
    {
    echo '<img src="http://mysite/image2.png" border=0>';
    }

if ($product2 > 0)
    {
    echo '<img src="http://mysite/image3.png" border=0>';
    }
else 
    {
    echo '<img src="http://mysite/image4.png" border=0>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Do you still accept an answer? Can you elaborate the structure of your database, the tables you use, etc.

Answer (score 0):

for storing check box value use name attribute as

```
$check=$_POST['product1']; //it depend on you what method you are using
```

if you echo $check it will give 1

Comment: I am confused how that would store the value you of the checkbox into the database so it can be changed by the admin over time